# Redirect one IP to VPN (openvpn)

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I have followed this guide about setting up openvpn for the first time and I was able to successfully setup a connection from my windows machine to the Ubuntu server where openvpn is installed.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

The reason I am wanting to doing this is because on the ubuntu machine is a website and I only want to be able to access this website from a specific IP (which is our main office) or anyone who has established a VPN connection to the server first.

It's the second part of this that is not working.

I have tried many things...in the client config I have added:

```
route 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 64.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 128.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 192.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
```

This works to allow me to browse the web while connected to VPN but I am still not able to access my site.  I don't think my VPN IP is being used when I try to access the site.

I have also tried...

```
route-nopull
route 10.8.0.6 255.255.255.255
```

and

```
route-nopull
route 10.8.0.6 255.255.255.0
```

This doesn't work either.